# When to load Gem code when depending on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, loading

I'm developing a Gem that is to be used exclusively in Rails projects. It has been developed inside of a Rails application's `lib` directory and is now to be extracted in a separate Gem.

Some of the classes depend on the Rails framework to be loaded though. Two examples:

```
class OurGem::Hookup
  CONFIG_PATH = 'config/hookup.rb'.freeze
  [...]
end

class OurGem::RoutingContainer
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  [...]
end
```

Normally, I load the Gem code in the Gem's main module file using `require`. But as this is loaded by bundler, Rails is not ready and things like `Rails.application` and `Rails.root` cannot be used. The first example could be worked around by not evaluating the path at load time, but the second one seems kind of tricky to me.

What is the proper way of doing this? Register an initializer using a railtie and require the "delicate" files there?

Answer (score 2):

This is a strange setup, because your gem depends on your rails app and your rails app depends on your gem.

This looks far too coupled to me. Have you considered creating a self-contained [rails engine](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) that your main app mounts, instead?

You *might* be able to get away with doing this, though:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'our_gem', require: false

# config/initializers/our_gem.rb
require 'our_gem'
OurGem::Hookup.config_path = '...'
```

This ensures that your gem is only being loaded *after* the rails application initialises - so things like `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` will be defined.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well, our Gem does not provide any engine functionality (controllers, routes, ...) itself, but it i.e. provides a mixin using the host application's routes. I'm not exactly sure how a Rails engine would help us doing this.